# I can't implement MarkerClustering, Conditional Visibility & Filtering by Type

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer, webflow

I'm currently having some difficulty implementing the following functionalities in Google Maps and using Webflow as CMS backend. I have used [**the following video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiO27kexjOs&ab_channel=OKAMA-RobinDesarcy) about how to link Google maps Javascript API to Webflow’s CMS to build out the basics, however I've hit a dead end trying to implement the following functionalities:

- Marker Clustering
- Filtering by project type and status
- Different types of Markers to denote the project status
- Conditional visibility within the info-window pop-ups (so that if a field is not set in webflow, the corresponding elements do not show on the page),
- Closing an info-window when another one is opened.

Here's the code used so far:
Here is also a [read-only link](https://preview.webflow.com/preview/google-cms-map?utm_medium=preview_link&utm_source=designer&utm_content=google-cms-map&preview=866654849db2ead76746de48d95b028d&workflow=preview) to the webflow project.

```js
<script>

  function initMap() {
    const myLatLng = {
      lat: 49.053078,
      lng: -36.260135
    };
    const image =
      "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/617bccba1ff41a17f1f593e6/61a7c8a2dfdf5e3d275c8d6c_Group%2010.svg";

    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      mapId: "a552ab80d59640f8",
      zoom: 3.25,
      center: myLatLng,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      fullscreenControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      cluster: true
    });

    locations.forEach(location => {
      let contentString =
        '<div id="content" class="map-wrapper">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        "</div>" +
        '<h5 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + location.name + '</h5>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<div class="map-info">' +
        "<p class='p-inline'>Field:</p>" +
        "<p class='map-stat'>" + location.status + "</p>" +
        "<p id='capacity' class='p-inline'>Field:</p>" +
        "<p id='capacity' class='map-stat'>" + location.mw + "</p>" +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="map-info">' +
        "<p id = 'clean' class='p-inline'>Field:</p>" +
        "<p id = 'clean' class='map-stat'>" + location.clean + "</p>" +
        "<p class='p-inline'>Field:</p>" +
        "<p class='map-stat'>" + location.c02 + "</p>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<p class='p-top-pad'>" + location.comment + "</p>" +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>";

      let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 375,
      });

      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: parseFloat(location.lat),
          lng: parseFloat(location.lng),
        },
        map,
        title: location.name,
        icon: image,
        optmised: true,
        cluster: true
      });

      marker.addListener("click", () => {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.close(map, marker);
      });

    });

    let markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
      map,
      markers
    });

  }

  <
  /script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here is a [link](https://google-cms-map.webflow.io/) to the staging project as well.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work.